# Move player javascript

Tags: javascript

I do not understand this part :

**self.keyDown = function() { keys[event.keyCode] = 1; };**

**self.keyUp = function() { delete (keys[event.keyCode]); }**;

explain what this code does, please)

MVC :
   Controller:

```
   this.init = function() {
      keys = {};
   }

   self.trgt = function(){
      if(this.event.target === myContainer.querySelector('#start')) {
         myModel.startGame();
         window.addEventListener('keydown', self.keyDown);
         window.addEventListener('keyup', self.keyUp);
      }
   }

   self.keyDown = function() {
    keys[event.keyCode] = 1;
   };

   self.keyUp = function() {
     delete (keys[event.keyCode]);
   };

  self.moveHero = function(keycode) {
    myModel.moveHero(keycode);
  };

  setInterval(function() {  
     for (let keycode in keys) {
        self.move(keycode);
     }
  }, 20);
```

Model:

```
 if (!sometask) {
   if (keycode == 37 || keycode == 65) {
     self.moveLeft();
   }
   if (keycode == 38 || keycode == 87) {
     self.moveTop();
   }
   if (keycode == 39 || keycode == 68) {
     self.moveRight();
   }
   if (keycode == 40 || keycode == 83) {
     self.moveBottom();
   }
 }
};
```

Comment: `keys` is an Object where each property is the key code of a keyboard key being pressed at a given moment. When the key is going down, we add the key to the object, when we release the key, we remove it. It's not used at all in the code you posted, but maybe it's used somewhere else, to know which keys are being pressed at any moment

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code in question:

#### self.keyDown = function() { keys[event.keyCode] = 1; };

#### self.keyUp = function() { delete (keys[event.keyCode]); };

is just assigning which keys are currently pressed. Lets say `event.keyCode = 37`, In this instance your `keys` variable, which is an object, will now have a property that says `keys[37] = 1`, and it will remain that way until the `keyUp` function is called, deleting it. Whiile `keys[37] = 1`, the character will continue moving left, and this will stop once that key is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.keyDown = function() { keys[event.keyCode] = 1; };

self.keyUp = function() { delete (keys[event.keyCode]); };
```

Translating to plain English:

- If the user press the `keyDown` (number 40) then set the key 40 in the object `keys` to 1.
- If the user press the `keyUp` (number 38) then delete from the `keys` object the key 38

Answer (score 0):

These lines are to set functions that will be called each time the event *keyDown* (press a key) or *keyUp* (release the key) are called.

So let's focus on the actual code inside the function :

for `keyDown`, it sets a variable in a dictionary to a value. for instance, if you press down 'a', 'a' key on the keyboard has some int value which is 65 (see https://keycode.info/), and it will set the `keys[65] = 1`.

As long as you keep the button press, this value will stay, but as soon as you release it, the value is *unset* by using `delete` .

And so on for each keyboard key.

Then the main loop of the game will look which variables are set (by using "for ... in keys), and will execute a move function for each variable that has a special values, corresponding, I guess, to a-w-s-d or left-up-right-down.